# How to redirect all http, https request in network to apache server for creating firewall in raspberrypi..?

Tags: apache, http, redirect, raspberry-pi, firewall

How to redirect all http, https request in network  to apache server for creating firewall in raspberrypi..?

For example , if i have 3 PC in my network with IP addresses as 192.168.1.8, 192.168.1.9 and 192.168.1.10 and if from any PC i try to visit https://www/google.com then i should navigate or redirect to some IP like 192.168.1.10.

I want to implement this using *linux* and mostly using **raspberry pi**.
Please help me..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is a Raspberry Pi router. There are multiple tutorials out there that accomplish what you need in different ways using the same principles. I included a couple links for you to read through.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview

As you go through the tutorials, take notes of what you don't understand and create new questions for the community to help.

Good luck!